# push通知を拒否の状態でアプリの削除→再インストールを行った場合、設定で初期状態が一部許可になっている

Tags: ios

手順：
1.アプリをインストール、起動
2.デバイストークン取得のロジックが走り、push通知を許可するか聞かれる→許可
3.iOSの設定からアプリごとのpush通知設定で拒否にする
4.アプリを削除して、再インストール
5.アプリ起動後、設定からアプリのpush通知設定を確認すると、「通知を許可」に変更されており、かつ「ロック画面に表示」のみ許可という中途半端な状態になっている。

ただし許可になってはいるものの、デバイストークンの取得は行われません。
（拒否にしたことを覚えている？）

補足として言語はswiftで、デバイストークンの取得ロジックはAppDelegateのdidFinishLaunchingWithOptionsで記述しています。
また、iOS8.1, 8.2どちらでも再現します。

これは正常な動作なのでしょうか。

Comment: 追記です。自分が作ったアプリでなくてもこのような状態になりますが、これが正常であるのなら、その理由が分かりますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

正常な挙動だと思います。
推測にはなりますがアンインストールした時点で権限等の情報も削除されてしまうのではないのでしょうか。(もう使わないものの情報を保持している必要はないですし容量を圧迫するだけなので)
権限が中途半端になるのについてはただ単にデフォルトの権限設定に合わせているだけかと思います